# What is a good way to implement a menu system for an iphone game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, menu

I'm working on a project and I've been asked to add a fairly detailed and nested menu system overtop pre-existing gameplay.  I'm new to iphone programming in general, but have experience with other C languages on different platforms.  I'm looking for an example of a good clean menu system architecture.

So far, I've gotten a little used to how the xib files interact with the code, but I still have a ways to go it seems.  I have two UIViewControllers; lets call them UIViewControllerA and UIViewControllerB.  I started with UIViewControllerA (the game's main view controller) and want to add UIViewControllerB as a menu to lay on top the game window.  The only way I've found to get UIViewControllerB to render is to use it as a data member of UIViewControllerA and add it as a subview to UIViewControllerA.

This seems like a very unclean way to organize this system and introduces some bugs.  IE - when I have UIViewControllerB showing, the touch events fall through to UIViewControllerA which I do not want.

Sorry this is long, but I'll get to the point.  Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to create a clean and robust menu system?  I feel as though I am way off the mark.  I don't think I have enough experience to come up with a good system on this platform.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I feel as perhaps I didn't specify that I'm seeking help for technical programming design rather than visual design.  I'm seeking for a way to implement a state-machine type architecture for an iphone platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link - https://github.com/relikd/OGActionChooser

It's a nice-looking replacement for a UIActionSheet or UIAlertView - this could easily be customized to present a modal menu system.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way to have a clean menu page, simply take a picture of hardwood floor (or off the web) and add buttons. I would show an example but I need 10 points...

Take the pic, onto PS (photoshop) and add a box or square, add shadow and some cool special effects, upload it to xcode, but the buttons in the box.

Comment: That sounds like good advice for the visual design, but I was looking for help on the technical side.  Thanks though. :)